# Google Play console Signed apk version code error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

I uploaded apk with next Version code only
For example my previous version code is 23 now i uploaded apk with version code 24.But Google play console showing "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle with an invalid version code, a version code must be specified and should be a positive integer"

I did not get any solution

Comment: How you changed the version code?

Comment: I had the similar bug. Google said something like "Your build version code is too low.". But when I increased version code +1 one more time it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go in the **build.gradle** and set the version code and name inside the `defaultConfig` element

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: hi actually i got this error while building instant app bundle. i did not mention version code and version name in build.gradle(installed module) but i mentioned in build.gradle(base module). after mentioning in installed module it is working fine and  thanks for your solution